# How to properly read c# process standard error stream without deadlocks?

Tags: c#, .net-core

It really feels like I'm following best practices according to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror?view=netcore-2.2). But I'm most likely missing something because my code hangs after continuing from this line: `string errorOutput = cmd.StandardError.ReadToEnd();`. What am I doing wrong?

```
        var batchfile = File.OpenWrite("run.bat");
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(batchfile);
        writer.Write("dotnet run" + '\n');
        //writer.Write("set /p temp=\"Hit enter to continue\"" + '\n');
        writer.Close();

        var cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = batchfile.Name;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        cmd.Start();
        string errorOutput = cmd.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        cmd.WaitForExit();

        var outputfile = File.OpenWrite("run_errorOut.txt");
        StreamWriter outputWriter = new StreamWriter(outputfile);
        outputWriter.Write(errorOutput);
        outputWriter.Close();
```

In case it helps: At the moment this code is running inside an xunit test inside a dotnetcore2.2 app (its target framework is 'netcoreapp2.2').

Comment: From [docs remarks here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) `Methods such as Read, ReadLine and ReadToEnd perform synchronous read operations on the error output stream of the process. These synchronous read operations do not complete until the associated Process writes to its StandardError stream, or closes the stream.`

Comment: It then goes on to talk about deadlock conditions and how to avoid them

Comment: I think I read that. Are you saying that the most likely culprit is the dotnet project that `cmd` starts via batch file?

Comment: I was thinking that last clause should apply here.. "or closes the stream" since right after I read from the error output I wait for the process to exit/close.

Comment: if the child process never writes to error stream. then parent will wait and keep waiting till one of the expected conditions exist.

Comment: Hm, my project shouldn't take long to run. Maybe it's not exiting correctly? But then you'd think it would write to the error stream.

Comment: @gordlonious If there are no errors and you try and read StandardError, it will read forever as there is nothing to read. Please see my answer or the docs for more info

Comment: Will do. Gotta get back to my dev environment first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I had a very similar problem not that long ago, doing almost exactly the same and what I found was that:

- Trying to read StandardError/Output without there being anything to read blocks until there is something to read (or deadlock if nothing is ever written - e.g. process has exited)
- `cmd.HasExited` is false until the StandardError/Output has been read so that cannot be used to detect when finished (and then read StandardError/Output)

The most reliable way I have found to do this is to use the provided events on `Process`:

```
var outData = new StringBuilder();
var errData = new StringBuilder();    

cmd.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => outData.Append(args.Data ?? string.Empty);
cmd.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) => errData.Append(args.Data ?? string.Empty);
```

And then after `cmd.Start() == true`:

```
cmd.BeginErrorReadLine();
cmd.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

To start the events firing.

After the process has exited you can call `.ToString()` on the StringBuilders to get the data:

```
Console.WriteLine(outData.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(errData.ToString());
```

(Note that `.ToString()` can be implicit when using `Console.WriteLine`)

Comment: Sometimes when debugging it's also useful to Debug or Console.WriteLine right in the event handler, rather than accumulating the output in a StringBuilder.  That way if your main thread is blocked on process.WaitForExit(), you can still inspect the output and perhaps see why the child process got stuck.  You often see something like ````Overwrite file? (Y/N):```` in the output and can intuit why you got stuck.

Comment: I threw this code into my test. I actually hit the `cmd.WaitForExit();` line, so that's good! For some reason my process doesn't seem to be exiting, but that's a different issue. I'm glad I'm hitting the next line but I'm also surprised that it's not logging an error since that's what happens when I execute `dotnet run` in my system32 console (I might try the event handler logging idea).